# push scene by tapping on image

Tags: webos

push scene by tapping on image. i am using one image when i am tap that image i want to push the new scene. it is not working. is there any way to push the scene when tap on image 
controle it showing error :  Cannot call method 'pushScene' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am talking about webOS which I have kept it in webOS. I've done it. Thank you.